# Reorder Ruby array based on the first element of each nested array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array

My goal is to convert a into b:

```
a = [["a","b"], ["d", "c"], ["a", "o"], ["d", "g"], ["c", "a"]]
b = [[["a","b"], ["a", "o"]], ["c", "a"], [["d", "c"], ["d", "g"]]
```

They are grouped by the first element in each nested array.  So far I have:

```
def letter_frequency(c)
  d = Hash.new(0)
  c.each do |v|
    d[v] += 1
  end
  d.each do |k, v|
  end
  end

def separate_arrays(arry)
  arry2 = []
  arry3 = []
  big_arry = []
  y = 0
 while y < arry.length 
    arry2.push(arry[y][0])
    arry3.push(arry[y][1])         
    y += 1
 end
  freq = letter_frequency(arry2)
  front = arry.slice!(0..(freq["a"] - 1))
end

separate_arrays(a)
```

Not only does this seem like overkill, but there are now guarantees that "a" will be a legit Hash key, so the last part doesn't work.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to do something like this:

```
a.group_by(&:first).values.map {|e| e.length > 1 ? e : e.flatten}
# => [[["a", "b"], ["a", "o"]], [["d", "c"], ["d", "g"]], ["c", "a"]]
```

I use the following methods:

[Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) (by first element of an array, like in your question):

> Returns a hash, which keys are evaluated result from the block, and
>   values are arrays of elements in enum corresponding to the key.

[Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values):

> Returns a new array populated with the values from hsh. See also Hash#keys.

[Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (required because you don't want to get nested array when there are only one match, like for `c` letter):

> Returns a new array with the results of running block once for every element in enum.

[Enumerable#flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

> Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of this array
>   (recursively). That is, for every element that is an array, extract
>   its elements into the new array. If the optional level argument
>   determines the level of recursion to flatten